# Create an abbreviation for "2>/dev/null &"

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I'm trying to compose myself a bash script with the intent of it being used commonly in a terminal. It should start an application as a background process and discard it's stderr output. Here's what I got:

```
 for app in $@; do 
    $app 2>/dev/null
 done
```

It seemed to work just fine with bare applications started without parameters, like `script.sh firefox gedit` but failed to do the following:

```
script.sh "vlc video.mp4"
```

My question is: How can I enhance this basic script to handle applications which take parameters/files as their input? Maybe there already is a tool I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. The use of `$@` without quotes.

   This would make the loop iterate over `vlc` and `video.mp4` as two separate items, even if these were within the same quoted string in the invocation of the script.
2. Using a command in a variable.

   If the command is anything more complicated than a single simple command, then this won't work.  You would have to `eval` the given string instead.

Taking this into account, your script could look like

```
#!/bin/sh

for cmd do  # or:  for cmd in "$@"; do
    eval "$cmd" 2>/dev/null
done
```

Calling this as

```
./script 'echo "hello world"' 'vim "$HOME/.profile"' 'tr a-z A-Z <"$HOME/.profile" | grep -c EXPORT'
```

would first run `echo "hello world"`, and when that finishes, it would open `vim` for editing the named file in that second command. The last command is more complex but handled by the fact that we use `eval` (it just changes all alphabetic characters to uppercase and counts the number of times the string `EXPORT` occurs in a file). It is run as soon as the `vim` session exits.

With this, you could even do

```
./script 'd=$HOME' 'ls "$d"'
```

i.e., set variables that are used in later commands. This works because the commands invoked by `eval` are run in the same environment as the script. This would not work if you start the commands as background tasks though, as the title of your question suggests.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying answer, I'll definitely make use of 'eval' now that I know about it.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently telling your script to handle each parameter as a separate application.  So you are running:

```
$ vlc
```

Then:

```
$ video.mp4
```

---

You should make your script more like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
$@ 2>/dev/null
```

Which, in my opinion, would be better suited as a function:

```
func_name() {
$@ 2>/dev/null
}
```

---

*Note: this will only allow you to run one command at a time.  I'm not sure if your original intent was to pass multiple commands at once to your script, if so I will delete.*